# How can I automatically kill all the processes and start script again in PyCharm?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, pycharm

I have a Selenium script that constantly runs on a server in a loop using PyCharm. Its average run time is about an hour, but I notice that every next run takes longer than the one before. I do use `browser.close()` and `browser.quit()`, but it doesn't help. At the end of the day, the runtime becomes over five hours long. However, as soon as I kill PyCharm and open it again and then run the script again, the runtime goes back to normal. Just stopping the script and running it again doesn't do the trick. Is there a way to automatically close PyCharm after the script finishes and then open it again to run the same script?

Comment: Provide some more info as: 1.Which Browser are you using? 2. Do you mean to say PyCharm have memory leakage? Can gather some memory usage statistics?

Comment: I use Chrome. The memory doesn't appear to leak too much. At least Task Manager shows RAM at about the same level (5GB used out of 10 GB available) even if the run time is over five hours. There is plenty of CPU left too.

Comment: Basically I work with Selenium (Java) and have recently using PyCharm for Selenium (Python) bindings. Though there is a memory leak issue but only on Internet Explorer which is under investigation. Thanks